# access denied for user aws secrets manager nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I have the code below in nodejs that retrieves a secret from aws secrets manager. I am currently getting the error:

```
"Access denied for user 'admin'@'pool-123-72-191-12.nfrvne.fios.verizon.net' (using password: YES)",
```

The code below is copied from what the secrets manager console told me to do within the secret:

[image]

When I press retrieve secret value, I get the correct values for the RDS database that I set up.

I am unsure what I am doing incorrect. Help would be much appreciated!

```
const config = require('config.json');
const mysql = require('mysql');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
require('dotenv').config()

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.NODE_APP_ACCESS_ID, secretAccessKey: process.env.NODE_APP_ACCESS_KEY});
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

var region = "us-east-1";
//not real value below
var secretName = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:432423432432:secret:some-secret";
var secret;
var decodedBinarySecret;

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.NODE_APP_ACCESS_ID, secretAccessKey: process.env.NODE_APP_ACCESS_KEY})

// Create a Secrets Manager client
var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
  region: region
}); 

console.log(client)

client.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}, function(err, data) {
    
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'DecryptionFailureException')
            // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            throw err;
        else if (err.code === 'InternalServiceErrorException')
            // An error occurred on the server side.
            // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            throw err;
        else if (err.code === 'InvalidParameterException')
            // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            throw err;
        else if (err.code === 'InvalidRequestException')
            // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            throw err;
        else if (err.code === 'ResourceNotFoundException')
            // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            throw err;
    }
    else {
        // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
        // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if ('SecretString' in data) {
            secret = data.SecretString;
            console.log(secret)

        } else {
            let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
            decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
        }
    }
    
    // Your code goes here. 
});
```

When I log client, it has correct access id i want for my IAM user:

```
Service {
  config: Config {
    credentials: Credentials {
      expired: false,
      expireTime: null,
      refreshCallbacks: [],
      accessKeyId: 'CORRECT ACCESS KEY',
      sessionToken: undefined
    },
    credentialProvider: CredentialProviderChain {
      providers: [Array],
      resolveCallbacks: []
    },
    region: 'us-east-1',
    logger: null,
    apiVersions: {},
    apiVersion: null,
    endpoint: 'secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    httpOptions: { timeout: 120000 },
    maxRetries: undefined,
    maxRedirects: 10,
    paramValidation: true,
    sslEnabled: true,
    s3ForcePathStyle: false,
    s3BucketEndpoint: false,
    s3DisableBodySigning: true,
    s3UsEast1RegionalEndpoint: 'legacy',
    s3UseArnRegion: undefined,
    computeChecksums: true,
    convertResponseTypes: true,
    correctClockSkew: false,
    customUserAgent: null,
    dynamoDbCrc32: true,
    systemClockOffset: 0,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    signatureCache: true,
    retryDelayOptions: {},
    useAccelerateEndpoint: false,
    clientSideMonitoring: false,
    endpointDiscoveryEnabled: undefined,
    endpointCacheSize: 1000,
    hostPrefixEnabled: true,
    stsRegionalEndpoints: 'legacy',
    useFipsEndpoint: false,
    useDualstackEndpoint: false
  },
  isGlobalEndpoint: false,
  endpoint: Endpoint {
    protocol: 'https:',
    host: 'secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    port: 443,
    hostname: 'secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    pathname: '/',
    path: '/',
    href: 'https://secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'
  },
  _events: {
    apiCallAttempt: [ [Function: EVENTS_BUBBLE] ],
    apiCall: [ [Function: CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE] ]
  },
  MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: EVENTS_BUBBLE],
  CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE],
  _clientId: 2
}
```

However, I still get this error:

```
"Access denied for user 'admin'@'pool-123-72-191-12.nfrvne.fios.verizon.net' (using password: YES)",
```

Let me know please.

Comment: I doubt this is related to the SecretsManager call, that error message does not come from an AWS service. Where is that script located, how are you running it, does it produce some log output, maybe add some logs to make sure you reach some relevant parts of the script at all.

Comment: That error is coming from a database connection, not from Secrets Manager.